How to write KQL to display each User who accessed a specific table in Log Analytic Workspace
I need help for a specific Log Analytic workspace, displaying the users who accessed it, the tables accessed, and the number of queries made by each of those users for each table. I tried to use the AzureActivity table but the result is not what I wanted.
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue contains "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/"
| extend role_ = tostring(parse_json(tostring(Authorization_d.evidence)).role)
| extend principalType_ = tostring(parse_json(tostring(Authorization_d.evidence)).principalType)
| where TimeGenerated between ( startofyear(now()) .. now() )
| where dayofweek(TimeGenerated) between (1d .. 5d)
| join kind=inner(
    IdentityInfo
    | where TimeGenerated > (ago(30d))
    | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by AccountSID)
    on $left.Caller == $right.AccountUPN
| extend RetraiteQuebecTime = datetime_utc_to_local(TimeGenerated, "America/Montreal")
| summarize  count() by Caller,Level, role_, ActivityStatusValue,  bin(TimeGenerated,1d)
| render columnchart

Thank you for your help,
Sincerely

Hello everyone,
I was able to find the necessary information simply by using the LAQuerylogs table.

Is your issue resolved now? @Louis Di Edgar

Hello Louis Di Edgar, seems like you already found a solution to your problem, I am just posting it here for ease of other folks who are facing similar issue on SO. Please feel free to add any points / your inputs to this if required.
To track each user who accessed a specific table in Log Analytic Workspace, you can use the LAQueryLogs table. It includes information such as the AADObjectId (which represents the user) and RequestTarget (which shows the specific resource or table accessed).
LAQueryLogs
| where AADObjectId != ""  // Ensure that the AAD Object ID is present
| project AADObjectId, QueryText, RequestTarget, QueryTimeRangeStart, QueryTimeRangeEnd  // Project relevant fields: Object ID, query text, table accessed, and timestamps
| summarize QueryCount = count() by AADObjectId, RequestTarget  // Summarize by user and table accessed
| order by QueryCount desc  // Sort by the number of queries made in descending order


If you wish to see the actual query text along with query execution time, you can use
LAQueryLogs
| where AADObjectId != ""  // Ensure that the AAD Object ID is present
| project AADObjectId, QueryText, RequestTarget, QueryTimeRangeStart, QueryTimeRangeEnd  // Project additional fields for query time
| order by QueryTimeRangeStart desc  // Sort by the start time of the queries in descending order
| limit 50  // Show a limited number of results for inspection




Good to accept the soln Louis?
